# Company acquired a website with existing users. Is GDPR announcement obligatory?

Tags: gdpr

When company acquires a website with existing registered users - is it **obligatory** (by GDPR) to send a notification/announcement email about the acquisition?

Comment: The company must update privacy notices (information to be provided per Art 13 & 14) to reflect the correct identity of the Data Controller, but whether the change requires an email announcement can be debated – data subjects must be informed, but it's not required to do that per email. What does the privacy policy say about changes and transfers?

Comment: Do the users (or the new company) reside in the EU?

Comment: Both companies are in US and only some part of website users are from EU.

Comment: The actual website policy says that all user information will be transferred to the new company in case of acquisition. There is no point that describes privacy policy changes instructions.